# String.prototype.substring giving wrong output when I pass in a variable

Tags: javascript, substring

I'm working on the coding exercise to build a text editor and add some operations like append, delete and move cursor. Can anyone please explain me why in the delete function, text.substring(cursorPosition + 1) gives me an empty string instead of 'ou!' like when I do text.substring(6).

```js
function textEditor2_2(queries) {
  // create cursurPosition, text and result text array variables
  let cursorPosition = 0;
  let text = "";
  let textArray = [];

  // append text function
  const appendText = (string) => {
    text += string;
    cursorPosition += string.length;
    textArray.push(text);
  }

  // move cursur position function
  const moveCursor = (specifiedPosition) => {
    if (specifiedPosition < 0) {
      cursorPosition = 0;
    } else if (specifiedPosition > cursorPosition) {
      return;
    } else {
      cursorPosition = specifiedPosition
    }
  }

  // delete text function
  const deleteText = () => {
    console.log(text) // 'Hey, you!'
    console.log(cursorPosition) // '5'
    console.log(text.substring(6)) // 'ou!'
    console.log(text.substring(cursorPosition + 1)) // ''
    text = string.substring(0, cursorPosition) + string.substring(cursorPosition + 1);
    textArray.push(text);
  }


  // iterate thru queries and apply callback based on operation type
  queries.forEach(operation => {
    if (operation[0] === 'APPEND') {
      appendText(operation[1])
    } else if (operation[0] === 'MOVE') {
      moveCursor(operation[1])
    } else if (operation[0] === 'DELETE') {
      deleteText()
    }
  })
  return textArray;
}

let queriesSample = [
  ["APPEND", "Hey, you!"],
  ["MOVE", "5"],
  ["DELETE"],
]

console.log(textEditor2_2(queriesSample));
```

Comment: It seems like `cursorPosition` is a string. If you append a number to a string it will concatenate instead of adding the number resulting in: `51`. Try wrapping the `cursorPosition` in [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: ahhh just noticed I was passing a number in the string type. Thank you for reply!!